# How can I force my computer to always use my external speaker?

Tags: windows, laptop, audio, speakers, usb-2

I have an [external speaker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09H65BHLT) (USB2 device) on my Aspire 5 laptop, as the computer's laptop is so unloud and tinny-sounding.

It works fine when it works, but for some reason, the sound sometimes gets swapped back and forth to coming out of my external and internal speaker. It seems like it might be dependent on certain frequencies that will make it switch, or something in how the original audio was recorded, because often it will switch always at the same exact spots (not randomly).

Is there any way I can force the sound to always be played on the external speaker, and ignore the internal speaker altogether?

I implemented harrymc's suggestion, but it still (bizarrely) doesn't work. These are my settings:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I wrote too soon; the external speaker is going on random wildcat strikes still; since the internal speaker is disabled, it goes from external to silence rather than external to internal. So the problem is with the external speaker and/or the recordings. I say the latter because it's always in the same places in the recordings where the sound drops out.

Specifically, I'm playing along with recordings of songs (I'm playing along with the bass part with a different amplifier/not connected to my computer). So they are songs playing from websites (such as youtube and scottsbasslessons) that are "dropping out" in spots.

**UPDATE 2**

I replaced the external speaker with a pair of Logitech speakers. So far so good.

Comment: If this is Windows, run *Control Panel > Sound > Playback*, right-click the other sound device (not the external speaker) and select Disable.

Comment: @harrymc. Thanks; there's actually another step between "Sound" and "Playback," namely "Manage Audio Devices"

Comment: @harrymc: That sounds (no pun intended) like it would work, but it didn't (the sound output still swaps back-and-forth between the external and internal speaker. I will update my question to show the settings.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas haha dude that's definetly Windows. 7, 8, 8.1, 10 or 11 - all of them act the same in this specific window. What could possibly change from one of them to another?

Comment: One more strong-arm method : Set intentionally the driver of the internal speaker to a wrong and non-functional driver (maybe not even of a sound device). This will disable it completely, but I can't guess the outcome of it.

Comment: @Netan , I know that.  I am trying to help better questions get written.  This site is for querying for answers .. the search typed in by a user will not guess intent based on existing knowledge.  The tags are the key.  If I am on a mac, I don't want to see similar sound issues on Windows.. or Linux but thanks for the comment. :)  Also, he did not have that picture when I wrote the initial comment.  That was one of the reasons for the comment.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I saw the tag of "windows" and the picture and it was clear to me. Apparently I arrived late to the party haha aaaanyhow I've already posted an answer for "how to force output to an audio device" and "what might cause it", so I'll just wait for OP's comment.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: I added the "windows" tag after the fingerwag/raspberry

Comment: Yes, your question is now polished!  Thanks for doing that! :)  +1

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven I just saw the update. Try to connect with AUX to ANYTHING else and see if there are drops. I initially suspected the sound-card itself. If it's only the speakers, it'd be smart to describe your exact setup.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to disable the internal and also set the USB as the default device. Try this.

1. Right-click on the "Speaker" icon in the system tray (bottom right
   corner of your screen) and select "Open Sound settings."
2. In the Sound settings window, locate the "Choose your output device"
   dropdown menu. Select your external USB speaker as the default
   output device. If you don't see the speaker listed, make sure it's
   connected and powered on.
3. To completely disable the internal speaker, right-click on the
   "Speaker" icon again and select "Sounds."
4. In the "Sounds" window, switch to the "Playback" tab. You will see a
   list of available playback devices.
5. Find the internal speaker (usually labeled as "Speakers" or "Realtek
   High Definition Audio" or similar). Right-click on it and select
   "Disable."
6. Click "OK" to save your changes and close the window.

Comment: Thanks; it seems that simply rebooting (I should have thought of that) does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If the sound is jumping from one device to another, it'd seem that the AUX-jack is disconnecting. You'd might want to try and replace the cable?

Windows won't move your sound otherwise. One other possibility is to set the application to always output from AUX - but again, it'll probably get disconnected and you will hear nothing, instead of the sound "jumping" to another output-device:

Go to control panel > sounds > "app volume and device preferences" ( at the bottom ). there you can control exactly where each application's sound should be played ( see attached picture )

[image]

Comment: Thanks; it seems that simply rebooting (I should have thought of that) does the trick.

Comment: I take that back; see my update from today (5/10/23)

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven haha so, just as I suspected! It seems to be the hardware itself. Try other speakers to see if that's the computer's fault or the speakers ( I bet on the sound-card side ), or check if there are new events in Windows Event Viewer, probably under "System" facility.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon-B.CrowRaven Hey man, I just got the bounty... have you managed to locate the problem?